# Completely replacing a project with another person's project using Git

Tags: git, replace, pull

Me and another person are working on the same C# solution in VS, and we've run into some issues with a project called PL (using the Pull feature on git only gives me a ton of issues and conflicts that I've tried to take care of with no results).

How can I simply replace my own project with his? I tried to delete the project and pull, but while his PL shows up -- every class there is said to "have been deleted or removed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply taking his repository and place it on your machine?

#### If you still wish to use your copy and just grab your buddy content

What you should do is clean your working directory and then pull out the new content that you wish to pull.

#### How to delete my project?

Simply delete the folder and clone the project again. You can grab the url from your `.git/config` file.

#### How to clean my working directory?

Few options:

- **`git clean -xfd && git clean -Xfd`**
  This will "clean" all  your files in the working directory so no file should be modified/deleted
- **`git reset --hard`** - reset your repository to the content of the last commit.
  This will bring back your repository to to your last local commit.

---

Once you have cleaned all the leftovers in your repo you are ready to pull the content from the remote repo (Your friend repo)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove your Git commit history and just obtain his project (along with its commit history), delete the project at the level where the `.git` file is. You can then clone the project down or create a new `.git` folder with the `git init` command and pull the project down in your partner's state.

Comment: `git init` will not create a new repository, it will "fix" your .git folder if there is a need to do so.